# Styling in iOS 5: UINavigationController *unless* in PopOver

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am styling my UINavigationController with a custom image, however, this looks quite bad in a Popover, is there a way to do this only for navigation controllers, which are **not** in a popover?

I currently do this in my `AppDelegate.m`:

```
- (void)applyCustomStyling{
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TitleBar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [[UIToolbar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TitleBar.png"] forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

So if you don't believe that it looks bad:

http://i.minus.com/joDeixTP7XLpl.png

This is how it should be (UIPopover-default):

http://i.minus.com/i97ORJTj5pjZK.png

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIAppearance Remove Custom NavBar Background for UIPopoverController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11334062/uiappearance-remove-custom-navbar-background-for-uipopovercontroller)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `appearanceWhenContainedIn`[1](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfcm/UIAppearance/appearanceWhenContainedIn:) to have more granular control of appearance based on your controller hierarchy:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIPopoverController class], nil]
                         setBackgroundImage:nil 
                              forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: That sounds great. I'll give it a shot

Comment: This works, thanks! So I did this: `[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIPopoverController class], nil] setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];`