# UIAppearance Remove Custom NavBar Background for MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uiappearance

I have a custom navBar image in the navigation controllers in my app, set using UIAppearance protocol. However, when sending mail through the app (via `MFMailComposeViewController`), I want the default navBar instead of the custom one. I tried the approach outlined in this question: [UIAppearance Remove Custom NavBar Background for UIPopoverController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11334062/uiappearance-remove-custom-navbar-background-for-uipopovercontroller) but it did not work. The code I used was:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MFMailComposeViewController class], nil] setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

But it had no effect whatsoever. My app is iOS 6+. Is this something specific to `MFMailComposeViewController` or am I missing something from this?

Edit: other approaches attempted:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
mailer.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
[self.navigationController presentViewController:mailer animated:YES completion:nil];
[mailer.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Setting `UIBarStyleBlack` has some effect as the "Cancel" button subsequently turns black, but the background image is still set at the old value.

Comment: Looks like the only way out is simply not to use `UIAppearance` but set the image on those navigation controllers that need it individually.

Comment: Did you have any luck figuring out how to do this with UIAppearance?

Comment: No, the only working solution was to stop using `UIAppearance` and just set the desired style to each navbar individually.

Comment: i am facing also this issue for ios7.0. did you find any solution for that?

Comment: The only solution I found was to stop using `UIAppearance` altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
[mail.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

This should reset the background image for just this instance.

Comment: Tried this one too, did not have any effect, unfortunately.

Comment: Try setting the background image after you make the call to display the mail compose controller.

Answer (score 0):

Remove custom background image

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

BEFORE calling,

```
MFMailComposeViewController *vc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
```

Point is to set any customization for Navigation Bar appearance before `init`.